# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError from LocalService but not from NetworkService

Tags: java, windows, dll, windows-services, java-native-interface

I have a program in java I run through a service I wrote who uses JNI to start a JVM and launch the program. The program dynamically loads other jni dlls when it needs to.

The problem is that if i run the service as NetworkService, the jni dlls load fine, but if i run it as a LocalService (which has more privileges and should be able to access the network) I get a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Netstar\build_0704_24_02\lib\JobExecutable.dll: The specified procedure could not be found

Some more details:
I run the service from a windows share, but before it runs java it copies all the jars and dlls locally. I tried using dependancy walker but it led me nowhere. I also made sure there are no network paths in my Path environment variable. One of the java directives is -Djava.library.path=C:\Netstar\build_0704_24_02\lib

Thanks for the help